# String is not printing inside function

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a Rock, Paper, Scissors program. We need to include four functions, getComputerChoice, getUserChoice, displayChoice and determineWinner. I'm currently stuck on displayChoice, I thought to display the "Weapon" chosen by the user using a string, but it is not working. Any help/feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void getComputerChoice(int& computerChoice);
int getUserChoice(int userChoice);
void displayChoice(int userChoice, int computerChoice);

int main()
{
    int userChoice = 0, computerChoice;

    getUserChoice(userChoice);
    getComputerChoice(computerChoice);
    displayChoice(userChoice, computerChoice);


    return 0;
}

int getUserChoice(int userChoice)
{
    cout << "Game Menu\n"
    << "-----------\n"
    << "1. Rock\n"
    << "2. Paper\n"
    << "3. Scissors\n"
    << "4. Quit\n"
    << "Enter your choice (1-4):";
    cin >> userChoice;
    return (userChoice);
}

void getComputerChoice(int& computerChoice)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    computerChoice = (rand() % 3) + 1;
}

void displayChoice(int userChoice, int computerChoice)
{
    string uChoice;
    if (userChoice == 1)
        uChoice = "Rock";
    else if (userChoice == 2)
        uChoice = "Paper";
    else if (userChoice == 3)
        uChoice = "Scissors";

    cout << "You selected :" << uChoice << endl;
    cout << "The computer selected :" << computerChoice << endl;
}
```

Comment: `userChoice` will always be 0, you don't retrieve the value from `getUserChoice`.

Comment: fixed by doing `userChoice = getUserChoice(userChoice)`, can't believe I missed that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: also you don't need a parameter for `getUserChoice(int)`, you just overwrite your input anyway, and you're not passing by reference either.  You can make it `userChoice=getUserChoice()` and it will work the same way.  Just make sure to update your function definition as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is one of scope, you're simply returning the value that you pass the function and not what the user provides as input, you should use a separate variable for this. Your get functions don't need parameters, also the getComputerChoice function should be type int. These changes should give you the correct output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int getComputerChoice();
int getUserChoice();
void displayChoice(int userChoice, int computerChoice);

int main()
{
int userChoice = 5;
int computerChoice= 5;

userChoice = getUserChoice();
computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
displayChoice(userChoice, computerChoice);


return 0;
}

int getUserChoice()
{
    int selection=5;
    cout << "Game Menu\n"
    << "-----------\n"
    << "1. Rock\n"
    << "2. Paper\n"
    << "3. Scissors\n"
    << "4. Quit\n"
    << "Enter your choice (1-4):";
    cin >> selection;
    return selection;
}

int getComputerChoice()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return (rand() % 3) + 1;
}

void displayChoice(int userChoice, int computerChoice)
{
    string uChoice;
    if (userChoice == 1)
        uChoice = "Rock";
    else if (userChoice == 2)
        uChoice = "Paper";
    else if (userChoice == 3)
        uChoice = "Scissors";

    cout << "You selected : " << uChoice << endl;
    cout << "The computer selected : " << computerChoice << endl;
}
```